# Assign value to the third column of a matrix for specific first and second column values

Tags: matlab, matrix

The matrix `A` looks like this:

```
1 1.1 0
2 1.2 0
3 1.3 0
4 1.1 0
5 1.5 0 
1 1.0 0
2 0.9 0
3 0.3 0
4 0.1 0
5 0.4 0
```

The first column represents `X` while 2nd represents `Y` and 3rd `Z`. As you could see, `x` values gets repeated every 5 samples.
and `Z` column is all zeros, I did some calculation and I want to add a value at specific `X` and `Y` value. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you want to insert an `z = 5` value for `x = 4` and `y = 0.1`,

You could do

```
maskRow = A(:,1) == 4 & A(:,2) == 0.1;
A(maskRow,3) = 5
```

**Explanation:**

In the first line of the code, we find which rows of the matrix satisfies both the condition. i.e comparing `x` with the first column and `Y` with the second column of matrix `A`. The `maskRow` gives `logicals` of `true` corresponding the row which satisfies both the above conditions while `false` for rest of the rows.

In the second line of the code, we assign `z` values to the third column of the particular row we obtained from the `rowMask`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to manually checking each column (could be useful if you have many columns) is to use `ismember`

```
maskRow = ismember(A(:,1:2), [4, 0.1], 'rows')
```

Another advantage of this method is that you can search for multiple different matches at onces:

```
maskRow = ismember(A(:,1:2), [4, 0.1; 2, 1.2], 'rows')
```

Comment: Nice with detecting multiple different  matches. For assigning different values to those corresponding matches, you need `arrayfun` right?

Comment: I meant if you wanted to assign the same value. If you're doing different values then you can use `arrayfun` or just loop or whatever